# What built-in codesniff could I use to ensure there are no spaces before parenthesis and after function name

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

Is there a built-in sniff to ensure that

```
public function foo () {
                   ^----
```

there is no such a space.

I couldn't find it in any built-in standard, or did I just miss it?

Comment: AFAIK, Popular code editors can sniff that out.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: `phpcs` aim is to check the code style regardless of every developer's IDE settings, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah right., but why do you really care about this `space` thing as they are perfectly legal ain't it ? It's just a `space` :)

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: because of code conventions. A lot of stuff is syntactically valid, but to help less experienced developers to follow the style guide I want to create the comprehensive ruleset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extend or create your own standard. This is an example how requested functionality could be added to the `PEAR` standard (which is default).

```
<?php
//DisallowSpaceBeforeParenthesisSniff.php

class PEAR_Sniffs_Methods_DisallowSpaceBeforeParenthesisSniff implements PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff
{
    public function register()
    {
        return array(T_FUNCTION);
    }

    public function process(PHP_CodeSniffer_File $phpcsFile, $stackPtr)
    {
        $tokens = $phpcsFile->getTokens();

        do {
          $stackPtr++;
          $type = $tokens[$stackPtr]['type'];  
        } while ('T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS' != $type);

        if ('T_WHITESPACE' == $tokens[$stackPtr-1]['type']) {
            $error = 'Spaces before parenthesis and after function name are prohibited. Found: %s';
            $place = $tokens[$stackPtr-2]['content'] . 
                $tokens[$stackPtr-1]['content'] . 
                $tokens[$stackPtr]['content'];
            $error = sprintf($error, $place);
            $phpcsFile->addError($error, $stackPtr-1);
        }
    }
}
```

The following file is located under: `/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PEAR/Sniffs/Methods`

Example:

```
<?php

// test.php
class abc
{
    public function hello ($world)
    {

    }
}
```

bernard@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ phpcs test.php

```
FILE: /home/bernard/Desktop/test.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 5 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 2 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 | ERROR | Missing file doc comment
 2 | ERROR | Missing class doc comment
 2 | ERROR | Class name must begin with a capital letter
 4 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
 4 | ERROR | Spaces before parenthesis and after function name are prohibited.
   |       | Found: hello (
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope this will help you